# SQL cross-table constraints

Tags: mysql

Consider these tables:

```
BOXES
box_id int
box_type enum('regular', 'special')

ITEMS
item_id int
item_type enum('regular', 'special')
item_box int (foreign key referencing box_id)
```

Now, is there any way to create a constraint that only allows items with item_type `special` to belong to a box with box_type `special` or only items of item_type `regular` to belong to box of box_type `special`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `mysql`, but generally I think you just want a foreign key for items `(item_type,item_box)` referencing boxes `(box_type,box_id)`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that I'd like to be able to do the reverse too (ie. only allow 'special' to be put in 'regular'), which wouldn't work with a foreign key constraints on the type, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

You mean having only items of the same type in a box. You'll have to make something in your business logic layer, RDBMS can't make these as far as I know.